# How to fire a cron scheduler every 70th minute using quartz?

Tags: c#, .net, cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I need to  fire a cron schedule every 70th minute. For example if one fired at 12:00pm then  2nd one should be at 1:10pm and 3rd one should be at 2:20pm and so on. How do I achieve this? Cronmaker.com suggests this, 0 0/70 * 1/1 * ? *

But when it goes past 60 minutes, it only fires every hour. Not the specfied minute which is above 60. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Simple Trigger for that. Then you can set the start time (e.g. 12:00pm) and repeat interval of 70 minutes and that is it. Cron Triggers are not suitable for these types of schedules.